# Complex MySQL query through relational tables

Tags: mysql

I am generating a query that returns a set of profiles that meet all the conditions posted below

I am receiving the data like so in Ruby, then making a dynamic MySQL query based on the contents -

```
[{ attribute_id: 58, parent_profile_name: 'Douglas-Connelly' },
{ attribute_id: 26, parent_profile_name: 'Brekke LLC' },
{ attribute_id: 35, val: 'Asa' },
{ attribute_id: 38, val: 'Stanton' }]
```

These are the current contents of the database

```
profile_attribute_values 
profile_id  attribute_id    parent_profile_id   val
6           58              2
6           26              5
6           35              nil                 'Asa'
6           38              nil                 'Stanton'

profile
id     name
2      Douglas-Connelly 
5      Brekke LLC
6      nil
```

I need to return all profiles that meet all the conditions - **profiles** that have a relation to **profile_attribute_values**, where the attribute_id is x, and the val is y, AND where the attribute_id is x, and the parent_profile name = y

**WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE**

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT P2. * 
FROM profile_attribute_values PAV
INNER JOIN profiles P1 ON P1.id = PAV.parent_profile_id
INNER JOIN profiles P2 ON P2.id = PAV.profile_id
WHERE (PAV.ne_attribute_id = '58' AND P1.`name` = 'Douglas-Connelly')
) A,

(SELECT P1. * 
FROM profiles P1
INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAV ON P1.id = PAV.profile_id
INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values PAV2 ON P1.id = PAV2.profile_id
WHERE (PAV.ne_attribute_id = '35' AND PAV.val = 'ASA')
AND (PAV2.ne_attribute_id = '38' AND PAV2.val = 'Stanton')
) B

WHERE A.id = B.id
```

This will return

```
profile
id    name
6     nil
```

which is exactly what I want, though the tricky part is the second parent_profile condition where I need attribute_id 26, and parent_profile_name: 'Brekke LLC'

I know this wont work, but I need this to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT P2. * 
FROM profile_attribute_values PAV
INNER JOIN profiles P1 ON P1.id = PAV.parent_profile_id
INNER JOIN profiles P2 ON P2.id = PAV.profile_id
WHERE (PAV.ne_attribute_id = '58' AND P1.`name` = 'Douglas-Connelly')
AND (PAV.ne_attribute_id = '26' AND P1.`name` = 'Brekke LLC')
) A,
.....
```

I am generating the SQL statement dynamically, so I really need it to be as clean as possible. I generally use ruby active record for everything, so I am a little babied when it comes to SQL statements. Thanks!

Comment: Condolences.  EAV is messy and inefficient.

Comment: I hope you have `PRIMARY KEY(profile_id, ne_attribute_id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like straightforward addition of INNER JOIN for every condition will do

```
SELECT id 
FROM profile p 

INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values pav1 ON p.id = pav1.profile_id
  AND pav1.attribute_id = '58' 
INNER JOIN profiles p1 ON p1.id = pav1.parent_profile_id 
  AND p1.`name` = 'Douglas-Connelly'

INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values pav2 ON p.id = pav2.profile_id
  AND pav2.attribute_id = '26' 
INNER JOIN profiles p2 ON p2.id = pav2.parent_profile_id 
  AND p2.`name` = 'Brekke LLC'

INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values pav3 ON p.id = pav3.profile_id
  AND pav3.ne_attribute_id = '35' AND pav3.val = 'ASA'

INNER JOIN profile_attribute_values pav4 ON p.id = pav4.profile_id
  AND pav4.ne_attribute_id = '38' AND pav4.val = 'Stanton'
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

@Serg's answer is effective and fast for a small set of attributes to compare, but it is limited to 30, i.e. hitting the maximum 61 tables that can be referenced in a query (MySQL 5.x).

The following is another equivalent but arguably more costly plan, however this one is not limited in the number of attribute tests (you would build dynamically the `must` table of UNION ALL rows, and leave the rest of the query as is):

```
SELECT *
FROM `profiles`
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM (
        SELECT 58 AS attribute_id, 'Douglas-Connelly' AS parent_profile_name, NULL AS val
        UNION ALL SELECT 26, 'Brekke LLC', NULL
        UNION ALL SELECT 35, NULL, 'Asa'
        UNION ALL SELECT 38, NULL, 'Stanton'
        ) must
    CROSS JOIN `profiles` p
    LEFT JOIN `profiles` pp ON (pp.name = must.parent_profile_name)
    LEFT JOIN profile_attribute_values a ON 
                   (a.profile_id = p.id AND
                    a.attribute_id = must.attribute_id AND
                    (a.parent_profile_id = pp.id OR must.val IS NOT NULL AND a.val = must.val))
    GROUP BY p.id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN a.attribute_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
  )
```

Comment: `... (SELECT pid FROM (SELECT 1 AS condNbr, pav.profile_id AS pid FROM profile_attribute_values AS pav WHERE <condition 1> UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS condNbr, pav.profile_id AS pid FROM profile_attribute_values AS pav  WHERE <condition 2> ...) GROUP BY pid HAVING COUNT(condNbr) = <number of conditions>) AS  filteredPids ...` May it peform better?

Comment: @Serg not really, because that causes a lookup for a row that could simply be a constant, and for each row it is using up some of the 61 tables MySQL can handle in a single query.

Comment: Also a great solution, though I can definitely get away with the 30 limit, thanks!